# About ICS on Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

Do **[ICS](http://www.overbyte.be)** in Lazarus is installed and works fine on all platforms?
I read somewhere that there is a problem with Linux. Is this problem solved?

Comment: "I read somewhere there might be a problem. Is it solved?" doesn't mean anything. Where did you read it? Have you confirmed it's a problem? (If it's not, it doesn't need to be "solved".) What does "all platforms" mean? You need to be much more specific about what you're asking. This is entirely too vague. (It's not even clear what you're asking about - I'm presuming it's the [Internet Component Suite](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), but there are lots of results for `ICS` if you Google it.)

Comment: If you have a Lazarus or Delphi programmer you should be familiar with all these items.
When speaking of Lazarus,means all supported platforms in Lazarus.
ICS that is familiar to all Delphi workers: http://www.overbyte. Just search on Google for it.You don't have to answer the questions which don't know it.

Comment: Umm...Did you check my profile? I'm quite familiar with both. :-) When asking questions on this site, you should be as eloquent with them as you are in your comments. (And when you try and insult someone, you should do some research first. <g>)

Comment: I did not insult anyone. I just recommended.

Comment: "You don't have to answer the questions which don't know it" is insulting, especially when that someone might "know it". :-) You should not make assumptions about what people might (or might not) know here. If I post a question on a language site asking about 'ABC', that might mean many things,  and it's my mistake for not being clear, even if I put `english` in the tags.

Comment: I apologize if I did not take it well. I've translated this with google.

Comment: for the problem you can search with google : "ICS in Lazarus"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ported ICS to Free Pascal in the 2005 timeframe, but I never maintained it, because I needed SSL which was back then still a payed option. The backwards compatibility all the way to Delphi v1 was also very frustrating.

At the time I mostly worked on console level (since my target was a server), but the last attempts showed designtime components could be made to work too.

Current status is unknown, but at the time Francois merged back most fixes. That's 7 years ago though. My guess is a died in the wool porter could do it in a couple of days. FPC is more compatible than ever.

I kept a small notes page at http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/ics.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try Indy Components from the [Indy project](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx).
They work well under Linux, Windowd and FreeBSD.